# Pension hasn't been paid in or is late, what should I do?

Tags: employer-relations

I received an email from my pension holder stating that my employer has failed to pay the pension in the correct time. I was recently hired after a 1 year apprenticeship at which time I paid for a pension with the company. I don't want to soil the relationship by moaning about my pension but I feel like I need to address the issue.

What should I do?

Comment: Email whoever handles payroll and/or HR for you to figure out what's going on. Not much else to do here. (VTC company-specific).

Comment: You are not "moaning about your pension", you are asking your employer to uphold their side of your contract. Big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just address the issue. You are committed to doing your job. Given that, the employer should be just as committed to providing you with the agreed salary and benefits. Dont be afraid to ask. If there is no reciprocal employer-employee relationship then perhaps don't work there.

Answer (score 1):

Your pension is part of your pay package, so treat it in the same way as if your salary hadn't been paid - speak to your HR department. Hopefully it's just an admin error (possibly something didn't go through correctly when you were hired as a full employee). If there is a pattern of payments being made late then it could be an indication that the company is suffering from cash flow problems.